# Clock signal in kit DE2i 150

Tags: fpga

I am working with kit DE2i 150 and I use external (SMA ) clock output(Pin J31) to get output clock signal. Value of clock in pin j31 is 50 Mhz? Can i change the value of output clock signal? I don't find the value of external (SMA ) clock output in user manual.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `j31` is not a pin, it's a SMA **j**ack.

The frequency, or even the very presence of some output there, will depend entirely on your design. That's why there can't be any info in manuals about the frequency on that jack.

The `J31` is connected to the pll's dedicated output pin, it is expected that you include PLL in your design and configure it accordingly. And yes, you can have a wide range of frequencies there depending on pll's exact configuration.

Comment: Can i use ALTPLL of megawizard plug-in manager to configure jack J31? I don't find exactly output signal to configure it.

Comment: @hiếunguyễn You can use megawizard to create and configure required IP, but you still need to include generated IP in your design, connect it to toplevel module's output signal and properly configure pin assignment for toplevel output signal. The pin corresponding to J31 connector is FPGA's pin AF25.